# python different output when run on bash and subprocess

Tags: python, bash, format, subprocess, ripgrep

I am running a script which internally calls a bash command and parses the output accordingly.
For example i am calling this command

```py
result = subprocess.check_output("rg result",shell=True)
print(output)
```

I get this output without any line number or anything

```
historyChecker.py:        result = subprocess.check_output("rg --help",shell=True)
historyChecker.py:        output = re.search(r'USAGE:',result)
```

If i run the same command in bash i get a different result

```
[~/history_checker/code]$ rg result                                                                                                                                               
historyChecker.py
56:        result = subprocess.check_output("rg --help",shell=True)
57:        output = re.search(r'USAGE:',result)
```

any idea why this is happening and how we can solve this.
Thanks

Comment: so basically you are asking why one "terminal" formats stuff differently than another?

Comment: Some programs change their output format depending on whether standard output is a terminal or not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the documentation of [`rg`](https://www.mankier.com/1/rg):

> `-n`,  `--line-number`
> Show line numbers (1-based). This is enabled by default when searching in a terminal.

So when you run it in a terminal, this option is enabled. When you use `subprocess.check_output()`, standard output is connected to a pipe, and this option isn't enabled.

Add the `--line-number` option if you want them.

```
result = subprocess.check_output(["rg", "--line-number", "result"])
print(output)
```

You're also not doing anything that needs shell parsing, so pass the command line as a list and don't use `shell=True`.

Comment: Alternatively, use `-p` aka `--pretty` to get the same output that `rg` prints to a terminal by default.

Comment: @thatotherguy Although colors might not be wanted.